# Why "interference" has pronunciation of "/... fɪə .../"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

We speak "interference" as: /ɪntə'fɪər(ə)ns/. However, I do not understand why we don't say it as: /ɪntə'fɜːr(ə)ns/? Just like the word "infer". Why do we pronunce differntly about "fer" part in these two words?

Comment: Why would we pronounce interference like infer, and not like interfere?  Put differently, we pronounce interference like interfere (and inference like infer).

Comment: In English we don't pronounce words according to their spelling. We sorta spell them according to their pronounciation, with lots of variations, exceptions to rules, etc., about what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interference is a suffixed form of "interfere", which is an Late Middle English borrowing from French, and shows hints of the  Middle French verb "entreferir".

Sometimes there is a sound change when a suffix is added, but more often than not, the pronunciation is carried from the root form to the suffixed form, as in this case. There is no reason to think that the pronunciation of an unrelated word "infer" could guide the pronunciation of "interfere"

Answer (score 3):

Yeah! From refer you get reference, for example. So, I think the problem is that interfere should be pronounced /inter'fer/, sorry i can't use the IPA in this computer. Then we would have interference pronounced as /in'terferens/. There is a difference between refer and interfere, and that is there's a final -e in interfere; so maybe that's why the pronunciation is different /inter'fier/.

Anyway, the first time I saw this word written down, I pronunced it /in'terferens/, influenced by the pronunciation of reference, conference, inference, transference, etc.